# Java Android: how to compare current time to a calculated time?

Tags: java, android, datetime, datetime-format, datetime-comparison

Good day.

I am trying to create a quiz answer form where there is a time limit.

The timelimit is defined by the teacher in hours and minutes. It is then added to the date-time where the student has taken the quiz.

```
int HOUR = getHour();
int MIN = getMinute();
String START_TIME = getTimestart();

    SimpleDateFormat FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, java.util.Locale.getDefault());
    Date parsed_START = FORMAT.parse(START_TIME );
    Calendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
    gc.setTime(parsed_START);
    gc.add(Calendar.HOUR, HOUR);
    gc.add(Calendar.MINUTE, MIN);
    Date TIMESTOP = gc.getTime();
```

What I want to do is compare the device's current time to TIMESTOP. If the two are equal or the current device's Datetime is greater than TIMESTOP then the quiz will submit itself regardless of the progress of the student.

I have tried so many ways to get the devices time, however most of it outputs the wrong time, or the date formatter I'm using does not work. It always say String cannot be used for date. But I have seen so many examples like this : https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-get-current-date-time-date-and-calender/ yet their SimpleDateFormat works. This is getting frustrating. So I appreciate any kind of help thank you.

Comment: You talk about `DateTime` but I don't see it used. You are using Java's (broken) `Date`.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1555262/1531971

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: When posting code to Stack Overflow, please follow the naming conventions: variable names begin with a lowercase letter and use camel case, not underscores. Respecting this will make life easier for those who want to help you and will in the end make it more likely that they will.